# Parse JS SDK + Angular + Ionic - Uncaught TypeError: object.get is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, parse-platform, ionic-framework

In my app.js file I have the below code to get data from parse. If if query parse the first time I dont get data from the view, but if I query twice I get info in the view but I get an error("Uncaught TypeError: object.get is not a function "). please help me resolve my error.. Thanks!

```
      query.find({

           $scope.getRsvps = function(params) {



    var RsvpObject = Parse.Object.extend("RsvpObject");
    var query = new Parse.Query(RsvpObject);

    if(params !== undefined) {
        if(params.title !== undefined) {
            query.equalTo("title", params.title);
        }
        if(params.discription !== undefined) {
            query.equalTo("description", params.description);
        }
    }


    query.find({

        success: function(results) {

               $scope.data = results;

             alert("Successfully retrieved " + results.length + " rsvps!");
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                var object = results[i];
                $scope.data.push({'title': object.get('title')});
                console.log(object.id + ' - ' + object.get("title") + " " + object.get("description"));
            }
            $scope.$apply();
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }



    });


}
```

angular file below

```
<div ng-controller="Rsvp">
   <button ng-click="getRsvps()">Find all</button>
   <span ng-repeat="object in data">{{object.title}}</span>

 </div>
```

Comment: did  you try `object['title']`?

Comment: For some reason it just stopped giving me errors..interesting. where would object['title'] be placed?

Comment: `object.get('title')` here